# About infinitives

Tags: infinitives, complements

[**Source**](https://archive.org/stream/TheGoldenCompass_201307/The%20Golden%20Compass_djvu.txt) (*Golden Compass*)

> "They're making too much noise to hear from the kitchen," Lyra whispered back.

What is author's intention of using "to hear from the kitchen"?

People usually keep calm to hear something rather than making noise to hear?

Isn't it a bit awkward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinitival *to hear from the kitchen* is not an adverbial of purpose, explaining why they make noise; it is the 'indirect complement'  in the construction *too X to VERB*. (It's called 'indirect' because the adjectival or qualified nominal intervenes between *too* and *to*.) The infinitival tells what action cannot be performed because of the excess expressed by the phrase with *too*; if an explicit subject is not provided, it is taken to be the subject of the main clause.

> I am **too** tired **to** think clearly.  *=I am so tired that I cannot think clearly.*
>
> He is **too** polite a gentleman **to** tell her she's wrong.  *=He is so polite a gentleman that he will not tell her she's wrong.*

You may paraphrase

> They are making so much noise that they cannot hear [the bell] from the kitchen.